# what is current subject in Shiro?

Tags: java, shiro

I'm new to Shiro and got confused about the current subject concept:

```
Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject(); // gets the current subject
subject.login(...); // do login
subject.logout(); // do logout
```

In my application I need to run work from different users concurrently, thus multiple users(subjects) co-exist concurrently, new users login and old users logout on the fly: clients sends work with [username, password] to server, the server do credential check by Shiro with the given [username, password], if [username, password] not exist in database, reject the work, if exist, login and dispatch the work to be processed, in the meanwhile other clients sends their work and login, my question is in a later time when the work for a user is done and I need to logout out the user, how do I get the subject for it?

Comment: Are you looking for scheduler support (Shiro has a quartz module)?

Comment: I'm not looking for a scheduler, just got confused that SecurityUtils.getSubject() and subject.logout() takes no parameters: which subject/user is returned? which subject/user is logged out if there are multiple subjects/users? My application is like a building which has a lot of rooms but only one entrance, people(user) check-in through the entrance and go to a room(to perform some heavy task, different people may work in different rooms), while done go through the entrance, check-out and leave.

Comment: Right now I only need to implement the entrance class, other parts like work dispatch is irrelevant. The checking is performed sequentially(one user at a time) as it is very fast, no need for concurrency or scheduling. As people come and go in arbitrary order, the entrance class needs to keep track of all the users, how to implement that with Shiro?

Answer (score 0):

`SecurityUtils.getSubject()` returns the subject bound to the current thread (typical web app pattern), the source of the session is typically from information in a Http Session or Http Request. (Shiro is NOT bound to the Servlet API, it is just a really common model). So in the context of your application, the request might be just some method call containing the current `User`/`Subject` (not sure how your application makes this association or authenticates them, but that is a different question).  This means you may not need to use `SecurityUtils.getSubject()`.

Once you have a `Subject` and if you want to use `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` elsewhere in your code, you could wrap the call in a Callable: https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#automatic-association (this is basically what Shiro's Servlet module does)